# JOOQ Doesn't Generate

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, spring-boot, jooq

I was following [here](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/code-generation/codegen-gradle/). I used `postgresql` instead of `h2`. I was able to build the project with some additional fields.

I created a package `database` under `com.example.demo`, but it was still empty after project was built.

build.gradle:

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        springBootVersion = '2.4.2'
    }
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:${springBootVersion}")
        classpath 'org.jooq:jooq-codegen:3.14.4'
        classpath 'org.postgresql:postgresql:42.2.18'
    }
}


apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'
apply plugin: 'io.spring.dependency-management'

group = 'com.example'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = '15'

repositories {
    mavenLocal()
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-jdbc'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-jooq'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    implementation 'org.flywaydb:flyway-core'
    runtimeOnly 'org.postgresql:postgresql'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
}

test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}

import org.jooq.codegen.GenerationTool
import org.jooq.meta.jaxb.*

task generate {
    def configuration = new Configuration()
    configuration
            .withJdbc(new Jdbc()
                    .withDriver('org.postgresql.Driver')
                    .withUrl('jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/vertx')
                    .withUser('postgres')
                    .withPassword('postgres'))
            .withGenerator(new Generator()
                    .withDatabase(new Database().withInputSchema('public'))
                    .withGenerate(new Generate()
                            .withPojos(true)
                            .withDaos(true))
                    .withTarget(new Target()
                            .withPackageName('com.example.demo.database')
                            .withDirectory('src/main/java')))

    doLast {
        GenerationTool.generate(configuration)
    }
}
```

Is there something I am missing? Why can I not see pojos and daos in `database` package? My database has only one table with 2 columns.

`BUILD SUCCESSFULL` when I type `./gradlew generate`, but nothing gets generated.

Comment: @LukasEder, thanks for jumping in. The output just shows `build success`. I assumed it would be called once I type `./gradlew clean build`. I think I am either lost between tutorials or missing something.

Comment: Hey did you find out the solution? I'm having exactly the same problem. @Eniss

Answer (score 2):

You can try `./gradlew generate --info` command, which will give you more information about the build process.

My gradle script is quite similar to yours. By using above command, I find out that the classes are actually generated, but in a different folder `/Users/{MyUserName}/.gradle/daemon/7.1.1/src/main/java`.

So I have to explicitly set the output directory with `def outputDirectory = projectDir.toString() + '/src/main/java'`.

#### This works for me

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'org.jooq:jooq-codegen:3.16.2'
        classpath 'mysql:mysql-connector-java:8.0.27'
    }
}

plugins {
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.6.2'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.11.RELEASE'
    id 'java'
}

if(JavaVersion.current() != JavaVersion.VERSION_11){
    throw new GradleException("This build must be run with java 11")
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

group = 'snorlax'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = '11'

//create a fat Jar with all dependencies
jar {
    duplicatesStrategy(DuplicatesStrategy.EXCLUDE)
    from {
        configurations.compileClasspath.collect { it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it) }
    }
    manifest {
        attributes "Main-Class": "com.snorlax.userservice.MainApplication"
    }
}

configurations {
    compileOnly {
        extendsFrom annotationProcessor
    }
}

dependencies {
    // Spring boot
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    developmentOnly 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'

    // Swagger
    implementation group: 'io.springfox', name: 'springfox-swagger2', version: '2.9.2'
    implementation group: 'io.springfox', name: 'springfox-swagger-ui', version: '2.9.2'

    // Lombok
    compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
    annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok'

    // RDS Connection
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa'
    runtimeOnly 'mysql:mysql-connector-java:8.0.27'

    // AWS secretes manager
    implementation 'com.amazonaws.secretsmanager:aws-secretsmanager-jdbc:1.0.6'

    // JOOQ
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-jooq'
    implementation 'org.jooq:jooq-meta:3.16.2'
    compileOnly 'org.jooq:jooq-codegen:3.16.2'

}

test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}

/************************
    jooq code generation
 *************************/
import org.jooq.codegen.GenerationTool;
import org.jooq.meta.jaxb.*;

task generate {
    def outputDirectory = projectDir.toString() + '/src/main/java'
    def configuration = new Configuration()
            .withJdbc(new Jdbc()
            .withDriver('com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver')
            .withUrl('jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/snorlaxRds')
            .withUser('root')
            .withPassword('123456'))
            .withGenerator(new Generator()
                    .withDatabase(new Database().withInputSchema("snorlaxRds"))
                    .withGenerate(new Generate()
                            .withPojos(true)
                            .withDaos(true))
                    .withTarget(new Target()
                            .withPackageName('snorlax.userservice.database')
                            .withDirectory(outputDirectory)));

    doLast {
        GenerationTool.generate(configuration)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this was my problem too.

Answer (score 0):

Your file looks okay. I had a similar issue (while using maven). Try three things (that worked for me):

1. check case of the schema in "withInputSchema" property. Try to pass uppercase PUBLIC.
2. try to change 'src/main/java' to './src/main/java'
3. add "includes" and pass .* in it (to generate for all tables in the schema)